# How can I secure Controllers in a Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have developed some Admin functionality (EF logic, Controller, and Razor UI for Audit Logs actually) that I've packaged into a Razor Class Library (RCL) and created a NuGet package.  I want this functionality available to users of the package, but I want to allow them to control the access security.  I would usually decorate the Controller with an Authorize Attribute, something like:

```
[Area("MyAuditLogPackage")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AuditLogController : Controller
...
```

But I don't want to presume the client's security policy and Audit Logs are sensitive data.

They could derive their own controller from mine, but the original Route would still be in their default Area Mappings.

How can I give full control of this over to the package clients?

Comment: Is the answer not ‘write some documentation’ for your package users?

Comment: No.  Well, there will be extensive documentation for the package :), but my question is how can I include the controller, allow them to secure it as they see fit, and not leak an unsecured controller from my RCL project?

Comment: `Roles` is just a string. All that matters is they have a way to provide one or more. For example: `Roles.All`. The better way may be to provide a policy name so they can then define custom logic. They can the register their policy by your name and your controller will pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than authorizing by Role, you could require that people using your code create custom security policies that are defined on startup. This would result in something like

```
[Area("MyAuditLogPackage")]
[Authorize(Policy= "AuditControllerPolicy")]
public class AuditLogController : Controller
...
```

The policy approach is extremely flexible so the policy might be a requirement that a user be in role Admin. It could also require other claims be present in the token, including custom claims.  Check out [Policy-based Authorization in Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

This approach gives a user of your NuGet package complete flexibility, but many might find it burdensome. You might want to canvas a few to get their opinion first.

Comment: GlennSills, this is the way to go.  Yes, it will be a bit of pain for users, but I'll provide documentation and a sample on how they can bridge Roles into a security policy which will be what most will want to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a extension method to dynamically secure your Razor Class Library routes.

Definition:

```cs
    internal static class IEndpointConventionBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static TBuilder AddAuthorization<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder, AuthorizeAttribute? metadata = null)
            where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
        {
            if(metadata != null)
            {
                builder.WithMetadata(metadata);
            }

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```cs
        app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "MasterData",
                pattern: "{culture}/{area:exists}/{controller=Log}/{action=Index}/{dictionaryName?}/")
    .AddAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute("MasterData"));
```